# Node.js view object in function and why property of object is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, function, bdd

I am new to programming  so any tips how to learn node.js will be highly appreciated and learning  via "Learning Behavior driven Development with JavaScript" book

Please suggest how I can view the object in the console log as well please suggest how I can understand why object property are captured as undifined as well as what is the best way to debug node code issue I am usinhg IntelliJ Community Edition currently

```
 var order = function (orderDAO) {
    return {
        display: (orderId) =>  { return {
            "items": [],
            "totalPrice": 0,
            "actions": [{
            action:'append-beverage',
            target: orderId,
            parameters: { beverageRef: null,
                    quantity: 0
                },
            }],
        }},
    }
}

console.log(typeof order),
console.log(order())
console.log(order.toString()),
console.log(order.items),

module.exports = order
```

### Output

```
$node orders.js

function

{ display: [Function: display] }
function (orderDAO) {
    return {
        display: (orderId) =>  { return {
            "items": [],
            "totalPrice": 0,
            "actions": [{
            action:'append-beverage',
            target: orderId,
            parameters: { beverageRef: null,
                    quantity: 0
                },
            }],
        }},
    }
}
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

use `console.log(order().display().items);` to print items

`order` is a function not an object and `display` inside `order` is also a function.

The logic inside is:

`order` function returns a `display` function while `display` function returns an object.

so we need to use `order().display()` to get this object.

As a new js coder, you can simply use `console.log()` to test your code

Comment: thanks a ton for the quick resposne I able to see the object property in the console logs now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Immediately Invoked Function Expression javaScript syntax correctly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

```js
var order = function (orderDAO) {
        return (orderId) => {
              return {
                  "items": [],
                  "totalPrice": 0,
                  "actions": [{
                      action:'append-beverage',
                      target: orderId,
                      parameters: { 
                        beverageRef: null,
                        quantity: 0
                      }
                  }]
              };
        };
    }();
    
console.log(typeof order),
console.log(order('ORDERID'))
console.log(order().items)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , I  will go through the shared reference